# Replace certain array elements with blankspace

Tags: ruby, parsing

Hi I am currently creating a parser to try and extract data from a csv file. I was trying to check for multiple undesired elements and get rid of them but I wasn't sure how.

Here is an example of the file:

```
#Saturday Logs

#Item                  #NumberofItems   #Price
Glue                   2 bottles        $1.99
Pencil & Eraser pack   1                $2.45
Sharpener (M)          2                $3.99
OmitThisLine
Markers                2 packs          $4.44 -sale
```

Here is the output I am looking for:

```
Glue,2 bottles,$1.99
Pencil & Eraser pack,1$2.45
Sharpener (M),2,$3.99
Markers,2 packs,$4.44
```

Currently I have code that get rid of some elements and produces:

```
Glue,2 bottles,$1.99
Pencil & Eraser pack,1,$2.45
Sharpener (M),2,$3.99
OmitThisLine
Markers,2 packs,$4.44-sale
```

Based on my research I found that I can replace a single line like doing so:

```
row.select {|s| s.include? "OmitThisLine"}.each{ |s| s.replace("")}
```

However I am left with a whitespace and I still don't know how to get rid of "-sale" instead of the whole line. In my case I want to check the file for any line that starts with "Omit" or "#" and get rid of "-sale".

Answer (score 0):

You can use gsub to replace just the "-sale" characters.  If "-sale" doesn't exist it won't raise any error.

```
s.replace s.gsub("-sale", "")
```

If you want to get rid of the entire line with "-sale" you can do something like.

```
s.replace("") if !!s["-sale"]
```

For deleting lines that match your criteria you can do:

```
rows.delete_if {|row| !!row["OmitThisLine"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Removing `OmitThisLine`

If you're using the CSV library, which is part of Ruby's standard library, and you're writing your output to a new CSV file, you can simply skip over rows that include `OmitThisLine`.

```
require 'csv'

# Open a new file
output = CSV.open("/path/to/output.csv", "w")

CSV.foreach("/path/to/input.csv") do |row|

    # Add all lines to new file EXCEPT those with OmitThisLine
    output << row unless row.include? "OmitThisLine"
end

# Close the new file
output.close
```

### Removing " -sale"

We'd probably better remove `-sale` before writing any rows to the new file, and there are a lot of ways to do it, but I would add the following line to the code above:

```
row = row.map { |column| column.gsub(" -sale", "") }
```

Altogether, it looks like this:

```
require 'csv'

# Open a new file
output = CSV.open("/path/to/output.csv", "w")

CSV.foreach("/path/to/input.csv") do |row|

    row = row.map { |column| column.gsub(" -sale", "") }

    # Add all lines to new file EXCEPT those with OmitThisLine
    output << row unless row.include? "OmitThisLine"
end

# Close the new file
output.close
```

And you're output file should look like this:

```
Glue,2 bottles,$1.99
Pencil & Eraser pack,1,$2.45
Sharpener (M),2,$3.99
Markers,2 packs,$4.44
```